# How can I sell large quantities of ore quickly?

Tags: eve-online

I'm docked up in Yarebap, that's where our corp HQ is located. I mine a lot in my spare time, and so as a result I've got lots of extra ore I'd like to sell. Amarr is the closest market to me, but whenever I post stuff on the market it takes quite a while to sell, even if my sell price undercuts everyone else there.

What is the best way to sell large amounts of high-value ore like Kernite and Omber quickly, as in 24-48 hours? I was thinking about contracts, and selling directly to other player corporations, but I'm not sure how feasible it is, so I wanted to ask for an expert opinion.

Comment: Define "faster" the rate of which you sell your ore is entirely based on the need of the market.  This question is not possible to answer in its current form.

Comment: It takes up to a week and a half to sell certain ores, like Kernite. I'm looking for quicker turnaround, like a few days or maybe even less.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, that's easy.
What you do, is you take that ore and you process it into minerals!
Those minerals will sell much faster and in higher quantities than the equivalent ore.

You might say "oh, that's such a bother, I don't really want to do that".  Well, guess what? Neither does the purchaser.  That's what they're buying when they buy minerals, the convenience of not having to process raw materials into the minerals they really want.

As usual, scout the market (and perhaps the nearby markets, Tash-Murkon is close to Amarr) and have a look at what the daily quantities traded are and you'll have an idea of how much you can move for what price how quickly.  Everything changes at the region boundary.

Comment: If you are doing this regularly, make sure your skills are up to scratch and you do so in a station with a corporation you have good standings with. Also, for speedy sales, generally, the nearer you are to trade-hub, the better.

Comment: This advice also works for tier 1 loot: melt it all!  Except the best stuff, [for example](http://eve-central.com/home/quicklook.html?typeid=4533#).  Then sell the minerals.  Buy orders in mission hubs prey on mission runners not realizing this.  Canny marketeers will place buy orders for common loot *significantly* lower than its mineral value counting on unwary mission runners to bang the sell button.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the ore up for sale in the region that the Amarr system is in, then your Sell Order will be quite visible for ore buyers, so in order to make it worthwhile for Freighter pilots to pick up your ore to haul, put it up for sale in large quantities, i.e. few large Sell Orders, rather than many small ones.